# How can I add more storage to a persistent usb with Linux mint on it?

Tags: linux-mint, partition, usb-drive, storage, persistence

I have created a persistent usb with Linux Mint on a 128 Gb thumb drive. When I first created it I guess I only allocated 80 Gb for persistence. Now that I have been using it for a couple months the storage I have to work with is running low. I don't use this usb drive for anything else but running and working on Linux Mint so I'd like to use most if not all of the 128 Gb towards this. Is there a way for me to add more storage (increase the partition size allocated for persistence) without having to create a whole new persistent usb with another drive?

Some more in-depth information if needed:

- Linux Mint 12.1
- Cinnamon Version: 5.6.8
- Linux Kernel: 5.15.0-56-generic

*****EDIT*****
I did some more digging and found this menu: [image: Disks Menu]

I notice I can resize Partition 1 to be less, therefore allowing me to make Partition 2 larger. I am guessing that Partition 1 is for the Linux Mint OS and Partition 2 is for all files saved for persistence?

Are there any downsides to doing this? What is the minimum amount of storage I should make Partition 1?

*****Update*****
I created the persistent usb using Rufus.

I also have this terminal output for more information:

```
mint@mint:~$ lsblk -o name,size,fstype,label,mountpoint /dev/sda
NAME     SIZE FSTYPE LABEL      MOUNTPOINT
sda    119.5G                   
├─sda1  44.5G vfat   LINUX MINT /cdrom
└─sda2    75G ext3   casper-rw  /media/mint/casper-rw
```

Comment: Please tell us how you created the persistent live drive (which tool/method) and also the current partition table. You can use the following command line: `lsblk -o name,size,fstype,label,mountpoint /dev/sdx` where x is the drive letter of the USB drive (replace `sdx` with `sda` or `sdb` ...). Please edit your original question to add this information and render the output of the command line as 'code'.

Comment: You can probably reduce the size of the FAT partition so that there will be maybe 50% free drive space (so total size 6 GB according to the screenshot). You can use `gparted' to shrink the FAT partition and to expand the casper-rw partition. A disadvantage is that Windows might no longer access the FAT partition. - You should also be aware that editing partitions is risky, so you should backup everything that you cannot afford to lose (your data files: documents, pictures ...) to another drive.

Comment: @sudodus I added that information next to "Update" in the original question.

Comment: @sudodus Also would I be able to resize the FAT partition natively in the disks menu? Selecting the partition and clicking settings does appear to have a "resize" option. Why would Windows need to access the FAT partition? Would this be in the case that I try to access the files on the usb drive through Windows without booting from the drive? I have most of my important documents uploaded on Google Drive so I think I should be good as far as losing any important data. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think you can do what I suggested in my previous comment, but not from the persistent live system. Instead you should boot from another system and the two partitions sda1 and sda2 should not be mounted when you use gparted to edit them. - And I repeat that you should backup everything that you cannot afford to lose before starting to edit the partitions.

Comment: Ah got it, I'll give it a shot. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't use the FAT partition to exchange files with Windows, then no worries about that.